# VueJS sending v-model property from child to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Let's say I have a Vue component like this one:

```
 Vue.component('child-comp',{
    props:['name', 'val'],
    data: function(){
       return {
           picked: ''
       }
    },
    template: '<div><input type="radio" :name="name" :value="val" v-model="picked"><slot></slot></div>'
});
```

And The Parent vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  }
});
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <child-comp name="fruits" val="apple">Apple</child-comp>
  <child-comp name="fruits" val="banana">Banana</child-comp>
  <child-comp name="fruits" val="cherry">Cherry</child-comp>
  <p>{{ picked }}</p> <!-- this throws an error -->
</div>
```

How can I pass the v-model property `picked` from the child component to the root instance. Only way I know of is `$emit`ting an event from the child component and later capturing the passed data in root instance. But as you can see, to access a simple property, triggering an event is overkill. How can I access `{{ picked }}` within `<p>{{ picked }}</p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `child-comp` is an input component you could use two-way props. These work similar to `v-model` but you can use them with your custom components.

```
<custom-input
  :value="something"
  @input="value => { something = value }">
</custom-input>
```

You can find out more about this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) and [there](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events). See [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/991) thread also. Good luck!

Comment: How can I access `something` within the parent component? In the end, `something` is still a property of the `custom-input` component and not the parent component.

Comment: To work with `v-model` your component should accept a `value` prop which in your case would be "something" and you also (still) have to emit an `input` event with the new value - it's basically the same longer story told short

Comment: Are you saying that there is no better approach than this: https://jsfiddle.net/eq8doebh/ ?

Comment: yep, that would be the way - in your case it should be `@change` instead of `@input` since our custom inputs are radio buttons

Answer (score -1):

That's easy:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello',
   picked: 'apple'
  }
});
```

And in child :

```
Vue.component('child-comp',{
    props:['name'],
    template: '<div><input type="radio" :name="name" v-model="picked"><slot></slot></div>'
});
```